# Web scraping using Selenium issue with same class name

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Im extracting some soccer data from a simple dynamic table using Selenium, but the problem is, when im trying to get the "text-center" class name, it shows a lot of extra data that i dont want.

I've tried using xpath and css_selector, but it wont solve the problem.

Site HTML:

Data 1: Score (Wanted result: 0-0)

```
<td class="text-center">
   <a href="/r/1571269/somedata" id="r_1571269S">0-0</a>
   </td>
```

Data 2: Odd: (Wanted data: 2.375)

```
<td class="text-center" id="o_1562530_0">2.375</td>
```

This is part of my code:

```
Score = driver.find_element_by_class_name('text-center')
for score in Score:

    print("Score: "+ score.text)
```

As you can see, they have the same class name, and when i run the script, it appears both togheter plus a lot of extra content with that class name.
Also i've tried by finding by id, but the id changes every time so it has no sense.
What do you recommend? THanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please post more HTML for the context of those `<td>` elements?

Comment: Not sure if i can send links https://gyazo.com/a79593080dfcbdaef4270a61ce3a7e95

Comment: You don't have to post the link. Instead of screenshot copy the block of HTML that contains both of the data you are interested in with possibly one or two levels of parents. Data 1 and 2 are on different tables, right?

Comment: The html is too long, but they come from a responsive table, and yes, Data 1 and Data 2 are in different tables

Comment: In plain text, what are you trying to achieve in this page, could you elaborate? 
Trying to get all the odds and scores? or mapping them?

Comment: Any way to contact you? I see you have xp in scraping

Comment: put in question url to this page. Or add some HTML as text, not screenshot. We can't copy text from screenshot to test solutions.

Comment: it seems all td have `id` with name started with `o_` so you could try `xpath('//td[contains(@id, "o_")]')`. You could also build more complex `xpath` like `xpath('//table[@id="tbl_inplay"]//td[contains(@id, "o_")]')`

Answer (score 1):

The question is really unclear... but...
if you have multiple elements that have the same CSS class name, you can find the text in each element like this:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('text-center')
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
```

- notice the use of `find_elements_*` rather than `find_element_*`  ... the plural version returns a list of all elements that match.